# Как авторизоваться сразу на двух сайтах?

Tags: php, yii2

У меня есть 2 сайта. Логин и пароль на них одни и те же. Когда я авторизуюсь на одном сайте, мне надо чтобы сразу же авторизовывался и на втором сайте.
Оба сайта написаны на Yii2.

Comment: Авторизация происходит через куки. Куки выставить работая исключительно на сервер-сайде невозможно. Отсюда уточняющий вопрос: домены у сайтов разные? В смысле, они не поддомены одного домена, или не на одном домене находятся?

Comment: На мой взгляд, самый простой способ авторизации в вашем случае (одинаковый логин-пароль) - сделать с клиента в фоне ajax-запрос на второй сайт.

Comment: Да поддомены. Я тоже думаю надо Ajax-ом сделать

Answer (score -5):

Попробуйте cURL в PHP, если AJAX не поможет.
Запрос должен происходить на уровне HTTP.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?